# What would be better for Django comet?

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django

> Django + Orbited + Stomppy server +
>   Apache
>
> OR
>
> Django + Eventlet + Spawning web
>   server

Orbited and Stomppy seems out of date...is that correct?

Or if someone has a better solution (with a good tutorial, please) , please list it.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't require **comet** specifically, I'd recommend checking out [Cody Soyland's Django + gevent + Socket.io](http://codysoyland.com/2011/feb/6/evented-django-part-one-socketio-and-gevent/). I've got a little app running using this technique, and I also implemented a similar server using tornado (with the tornadio socket.io server tacked on) but in the end gevent was a better fit for my project.

While socket.io is still developing and maturing, it's pretty nice to use from a developer's stand point. Decent support for many browsers. Gracefully degrades to use different polling techniques depending on the browser, etc.